# Keyup() delaying

Tags: jquery, keyup

I am using the keyup function on JQuery to add a class to a div whenever the user presses a character or something and remove a class when they hit backspace. But the keyup function has a small delay. I have tried using keypress and it has no delays, however, it does not detect backspaces so I cant use it.

Does anyone know how to stop the delay on keyup or an alternative function that I could use?

Comment: "I have tried using keypress and it has no delays" - "Does anyone know how to stop the delay"... wat?

Comment: Sorry, I will rephrase the question.

Comment: I have tried using the keyup function but it has a small delay between the user pressing the key and it running a inner function.

Comment: What do you mean by small delay?

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is add a class to a div whenever a user presses a key. This is to change the visibility of it. However, when I use the `keyup` function, there is a delay between the user pressing the key and the `addClass` function running. What I have found is that there is no delay when I use `keypress` and there is a delay when I use `keyup`. But I cannot use `keypress` because it does not detect backspaces.

Comment: Ok, how much delay are we talking about? Are you using fadeIn/out or just hide/show?

Comment: Just incase I have caused confusion, I want to have no delay between the user pressing a key and the hide, show functions funning.

Comment: The delay is that.. the keyup doesn't trigger until the key goes up.. on keypress it triggers and a key is pressed http://jsfiddle.net/KFkUL/

Comment: wirey: Ok, so is there another function with the functionality of `keyup`, with no delay like `keypress`?

Comment: @Qiang: Why not use `keydown` instead, which does detect backspace. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the keyup function has a small delay. I have tried using keypress
>   and it has no delays, however, it does not detect backspaces so I cant
>   use it.

The small delay you experience is due to the fact that `keyup` doesn't trigger until the user releases the key.

If you do **not** want a delay use [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) instead.

```
$('#target').keydown(function(eventData) {

    if(eventData.which === 8){
        // Backspace was pressed
    } else {
        // another key was pressed
    }
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/M8dF3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $('html').keyup(function(e){

        var d1 = new Date().getMilliseconds();

        if(e.which === 8){
            alert('Backspace pressed, delay: ' + new Date().getMilliseconds() - d1) + 'ms';
        }   

    });
});
```

Comment: `which` normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode` properties.

Answer (score 1):

You taking about something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer,
        container = $('p');

    function doSomething()
    {
        container.text(new Date());
    }

    $('#find').keyup(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer= setTimeout(doSomething, 200);
    });
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tXJAz/